# Cannot find module '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox'

Tags: alchemy

[image]

I meet this issue when try to run the js file

Comment: You're not giving enough information. What code are you trying to run? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 16):

Simply install the package by entering `yarn add --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` or `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`.

But if you are getting the same error again and again and the package is present in package.json then you might be using npm and yarn parallely, just uninstall either of it and you are good to go.

Comment: why is this step needed? why didn't 'yarn add hardhat' add all basic things? thank you

Answer (score 3):

Please provide your 'hardhat.config.js' and 'package.json' file screenshots. To provide the answer, such information is necessary.

In my opinion, you may not have installed all the required packages.
Please check if you have the following things in your files:

1. `require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");` make sure you have this in your hardhat.config.js file. If not, replace the first line of the file with the above code.
2. Also, check if you have `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` this dependency in your package.json file, If not, you may install it using any package manager (npm or yarn) with the command `npm i @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`.

This should work, if it doesn't then please provide more information.

Comment: should be `npm install` instead of `npm i`.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the ethers dependency with `yarn remove ethers` than you can install and add hardhat again, that worked for me
You have to do this because hardhat has it's own ethers module, otherwise the two would get in each other's way

Answer (score 1):

npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox --force

INSTALL FORCEFULLY

Answer (score 0):

I simply installed the package using `npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox` and then tried compiling and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me reinstalling the nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox didnt work. I got error

> Error HH801: Plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox requires the
> following dependencies to be installed:

To fix it and deploy my project I had to install all the dependencies using the command

```
npm install --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan chai ethers hardhat-gas-reporter solidity-coverage @typechain/hardhat typechain @typechain/ethers-v5 @ethersproject/abi @ethersproject/providers
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I simply write this command:

```bash
npm install -i --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox --force
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35103514)

Answer (score 0):

I think is not working without `--force`. Problem simple solve when I use this code below:

```
npm install -i --save-dev @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox --force
```